# Convergence in distribution and integration

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Let $X_n\in\mathbb{R}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of random variables converging in distribution to $X$. Then, for any bounded Lipschitz function $f$ we have that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}E[f(X_n)]=E[f(X)]$.

Can we show that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int_0^\infty E[g(y,X_n)]dy = \int_0^\infty E[g(y,X)]dy
$$
where $g$ is a bounded Lipschitz function with $\int_0^\infty g(y,x)dy<\infty$ for any finite $x$.

If not, what additional conditions are needed.

Comment: No, just make a deterministic counter-example with $X=0, X_n=1/n$, $g(y,x)=[x]_0^1$ being a projection to interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: In this case $\int_0^\infty g(y,x)dy = [x]^1_0 \int_0^\infty dy=\infty$ for any $x>0$ which is at odds with one assumption made.

Comment: I didn't notice the requirement $\int_0^{\infty} g(y,x)dy<\infty$ for all $x$.  But you can just modify the $g$ function to meet that requirement (make it go to zero when $y>1/x$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a counter-example (modified from my comments): Take the deterministic case $X=0, X_n=1/n$ for $n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$.

It will be easier to define $g(x,y)$ over the domain $D = \{(x,y): x \in [0,1], y\geq 0\}$: 
$$ g(x,y)=xe^{-xy} \quad \forall (x,y) \in D$$
Then:
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} g(x,y)dy = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0 &\mbox{ if $x =0$} \\
1  & \mbox{ if $x>0$} 
\end{array}
\right.$$
Thus
$$ \int_0^{\infty} g(X,y)dy =0$$
But 
$$ \int_0^{\infty} g(X_n, y)dy = 1 \quad \forall n \in \{1, 2, 3, ...\}$$
Note $g$ is bounded because $0\leq g(x,y)\leq 1$ for all $(x,y)\in D$. Finally, note that $g$ is  Lipschitz continuous (see Note below). $\Box$

---

Note: To show $g$ is Lipschitz we note it is continuously differentiable and for all $(x,y) \in D$: 
$$[\partial g/\partial x; \partial g/\partial y] = [(1-xy)e^{-xy}; -x^2e^{-xy}] $$
and so 
\begin{align}
||[\partial g/\partial x; \partial g/\partial y]||^2&= (1-xy)^2e^{-2xy} + x^4e^{-2xy}\\
&\overset{(a)}{\leq} (1-xy)^2e^{-2xy} + e^{-2xy}\\
&\overset{(b)}{\leq} \sup_{t\geq 0} \left\{(1-t)^2e^{-2t} + e^{-2t}\right\}\\
&\overset{(c)}= 2
\end{align}
where (a) holds because $x \in [0,1]$ so $x^4\leq 1$; (b) holds because $xy \geq 0$; (c) holds because the supremum is achieved at $t=0$.

Comment: On the positive side: Your fact can be proven by Lebesgue dominated convergence theory if you change $\int_0^{\infty}$ to $\int_0^b$ for any (finite) $b>0$.